# What does it mean to clap back the rhythm? (Grade 6 Piano Aural)

Tags: piano, abrsm

I have a grade 6 ABRSM piano exam in about 1 hour. What does clap back the rhythm mean? Is it a memorizing one or clapping the strong beat?

Comment: I am doing ABRSM by the way.

Answer (score 5):

The examiner will play you a short (~10 seconds) line of music. You need to 'clap back' the rhythm he just played - so in the terms you used above, 'memorizing', not 'clapping the strong beat'.

This is based on my own exams which were 5-10 years ago now, but I doubt it will have changed.

From the specification on [ABRSM's website](http://us.abrsm.org/en/our-exams/aural-tests/):

> **To clap the rhythm of the notes in an extract from the same piece, and
>   to identify whether it is in two time, three time or four time.** The
>   examiner will play the extract twice (unharmonized), after which the
>   candidate should clap back the rhythm. The examiner will then ask
>   whether the music is in two time, three time or four time. The
>   candidate is not required to state the time signature.

Comment: So basically I need to memorize it and then clap every note back?

Comment: Yes, I believe so.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what they mean. I took my grade 6 recorder a few years ago and it has the same aural module in it (naturally). They want to test if you can hear and memorise rhythm.